# Where did the reset come from?

Tags: grimm

At the end of the last episode of *Grimm*,

> the Zerstorer has killed basically the entire cast of the show, save Nick.

After killing the Zerstorer (somehow; it wasn't made very clear how), Nick realizes he can use the staff to bring the dead back to life, as the Zerstorer did. *Before* he can attempt this, however, a portal to the other place<sup>1</sup> forms from the ashes of the Zerstorer, and he and the staff are dragged, apparently unwillingly, through it, emerging on the other side where the events caused by the emergence of the Zerstorer apparently have not happened.

What caused this? Was it Nick using the staff to restore his friends to life? Besides it being a very roundabout way of doing things, Nick seemed distinctly unwilling to be sucked into the portal. Was it some unconscious expression of his desires? A [lack of ontological inertia](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoOntologicalInertia) from the death of the Zerstorer? What, exactly, was going on?

<sub>1: [Funny.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_other_place)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can find is what is written in the diary that Kelly Schade-Burkhardt is keeping at the end of the series.

> Yet, Nick Burkhardt tried. With the fate of the world and the souls of his friends at stake, he threw himself at the unstoppable force out of desperation, not realizing that by completing the Staff he would gain control over it, and **inadvertently returning him to the beginning of Zerstörer's invasion of our world.** When he found himself back in his world, his friends alive again, looking down at him, he didn't know what to tell them... this time Zerstörer did not come through the mirror anywhere in the world, because in the final epic battle with the terrible Beast from the Other Place, Nick Burkhardt discovered the only way to defeat such evil was with the Strength of His Blood: his Aunt Marie, his mother, Kelly, and Trubel, his 3rd cousin on his mother's side, the power of our ancestors. - [Zertorer](https://grimm.fandom.com/wiki/Zerst%C3%B6rer)